# Permission Declaration Form for SMS in Android

Tags: android

My question is not how to implement SMS in android. I just want to get clarification regarding a post which says something about removing apps from Google store that ask for SMS permission for those that have not submitted a permission Declaration form.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html …

Comment: Is there a specific question you have about this?

Comment: Yes. Here at work, I want to implement a feature that enables a user to send a message via SMS on the app. And I will have to request for permission in the manifest file. So I want to know if I have to fill the form before I implement it. Or i don't need to be bothered about it.

Comment: See this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102

Answer (score 1):

The permission declaration form is more or less useless. Google wants to remove all Apps which use read/write SMS from the store.

There are a few cases in which the declaration form helped. Tasker was allowed to use read/write SMS but that was an exception because Tasker is very popular.

If you want to use read/write SMS in your App you won't be able to publish it on the Play Store. Google won't allow it.

This all happened because some developers from India and China used read/write SMS for illegal activities.

There still are ways to send SMS from your App but you are not allowed to use read/write SMS permission or do it automatically from you App.

Read more here:

https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually pushed to play store with the permission declared in my manifest. And as expected, it threw the error. So as suggested i removed the permission and used and Intent to open the default SMS app. But still use my app to get the to and message body. And am good!

Comment: Nice that I could help you with your question. Feel free to upvote if your issue is solved. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The Answer suggested above worked for me. I used an Intent to open the default SMS app. And yes the permission declaration form is real. So i will advice looking for an alternative to figure out the problem.